# Angular js How to populate dropdown with JSON without ng-options

Tags: angularjs

i populate drop down this way and data is coming but no data has been selected when dropdown shown first time. here is my code. please have a look and tell me where i made the mistake.

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
<select ng-model="selectedCountry">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in chooseCountries" value="item.countryId">
  {{item.countryId}}-{{item.name}}
</option>    
</select>  

<span>Selected country id is {{selectedCountry.countryId}}</span>   
</div>

var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chooseCountries=[
        {countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
        {countryId : 2, name : "Gibraltar", desc: "some description"},
        {countryId : 3, name : "Malta", desc: "some description"}
    ];

    $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.chooseCountries[0].countryId;
});
```

Comment: `ngValue` not `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More better way to go for it would be using `ng-options` directive.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" 
  ng-options="country.countryId as (country.name+'-'+country.desc) for country in chooseCountries">
</select>
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0mYWzQ1SRIqy93AXzK7?p=preview)

---

### Why `ng-repeat` approach wouldn't work?(*Just for explanation, not recommending to use*)

You should fill option `value` attribute with `countryId` correctly like `value="{{item.countryId}}"`

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry">
   <option value="">Select Account</option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in chooseCountries" value="{{item.countryId}}">
    {{item.countryId}}-{{item.name}}
  </option>    
</select>
```

But above will not work for your case because you had `countryId` field is in number format, when `option` assign that value to `value` attribute it gets converted to `string` format. So on initial load you wouldn't see `countryId` gets binded to select box. comparison will occur like `2==="2"` wouldn't be `true`, so select box would not select value, even if you provided in `ng-model`.

You can find the problem [**plunkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/evQJAKvMnl4btz4BZeuP?p=preview)

So for fixing it you need to convert that `number` value to `string` value by calling `toString` method over it like below

```
$scope.selectedCountry = $scope.chooseCountries[0].countryId.toString();
```

By doing above change select box does select provided `countryId` value in dropdown because of comparison occurs true `"2"==="2"`

That's why using ng-options would be better, which does preserve value `datatype`. Basically they worked without harm the datatypes of value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/evQJAKvMnl4btz4BZeuP?p=preview

Comment: can u plzz provide js fiddle?

Comment: @Mou check added plunkr

Comment: yes check and found u use ng-options instead of ng-reprater in your code. show me ng-reprater for dropdown.

Comment: @Mou do look at updated answer... where I explained why `ng-repeat` part doesn't work.. and do +1 if you can :p

Answer (score 2):

```
<select ng-options="country as country.countryId+  ' (' + country.name + ')' for country in chooseCountries  ng-model="selectedCountry "></select>
```

refer:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-options as follows

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.countryId as country.name for country in  chooseCountries"></select>
```

Comment: tell me why we need to write field name this way `country.countryId as country.name for country in  chooseCountries` why can't we write like `country.countryId,country.name for country in  chooseCountries` ?

Comment: I don't think value,label works here. As per documentation following are options for using in ng-options if source is array. `for array data sources:
label for value in array,
select as label for value in array,
label group by group for value in array,
label disable when disable for value in array,
label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr,
label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr,
label for value in array | orderBy:orderexpr track by trackexpr (for including a filter with track by)`