# How to bind array data to dropdown in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I am trying to bind data to drodpown. I am making ajax call to get data from server. I am getting error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I am making get request. This is my api. http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/Customer/Nationalities

Above api will return

```
{"status":"Success","msg":"Success","code":"200","data":[{"ID":1,"Nationality":"indian"},{"ID":2,"Nationality":"england"}]}
```

I am binding using js as below.

```
  var url = cfg.Baseurl;
            var nationality = new Array();
            $http.get(url + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'Nationalities').success(function (data) {
                $.map(data.data.Nationality, function (item) {
                    nationality.push(item);
                    console.log(item);
                });
                $scope.nationalityList = nationality;
            }).error(function (status) {
            });
```

This is my html code.

```
   <select ng-model="user.nationality" id="brand" ng-options="user.nationality for user in nationalityList" required>
                            <option value="" label="Select">Select</option>
                        </select>
```

I ended up with Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In your controller, can you try initializing your array to an empty array.. `$scope.nationalityList = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo link [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u8eze0zq/1/)

**JS code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.nationalityList = {
      "status": "Success",
      "msg": "Success",
      "code": "200",
      "data": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Nationality": "indian"
      }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Nationality": "england"
      }]
    };
  });
```

** HTML **

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>

    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
      <select ng-model="user.nationality" id="brand" ng-options="user.Nationality for user in nationalityList.data" required>
        <option value="" label="Select">Select</option>
      </select>
      <span>nationality = {{user.nationality}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this will help you out

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is not necessary to map, it only assigns the value of the array

```
var url = cfg.Baseurl;
var nationality = [];
$http.get(url + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'Nationalities')
.success(function (data) {
    if(data.data) {
        // Here the value is assigned
        $scope.nationalityList = data.data;
    }
}).error(function (status) { });
```

And your html has to go like this

```
<select
    ng-model="selectedNationality"
    id="brand"
    ng-options="item.Nationality for item in nationalityList" 
    required>
    <option value="" label="Select">Select</option>
</select>
<!-- Showing selected option -->
<p ng-if="selectedNationality">Selected option: {{selectedNationality}}<p/>
```

For more information https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1):

Because `$scope.nationalityList` is not initialized, it is undefined at the time when the view is being rendered. Hence the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error.`.

Just initializing the variable to an empty array will solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

Use `$scope.anArray =[];`

Bind the data to array from `$http` response.

[Angular js How to populate dropdown with JSON without ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401669/angular-js-how-to-populate-dropdown-with-json-without-ng-options)

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/evQJAKvMnl4btz4BZeuP?p=preview

I am sure you are using Json object response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.map(data.data.Nationality, function (item) {
                    nationality.push(item);
                    console.log(item);
                });
```

data.data.Nationality is not valid,as data.data is an array and not object
so, nationality = data.data 
would work fine